# Minifying JavaScript Effectively With Php

Tags: php, regex, arguments, minify, jsmin

Hi everyone i have a Php function which use **JSMin** to Minify JavaScript but i want a regex to replace
**long arguments name with a or b**

`function foo(long_arg_name, long_arg_name2){
 alert(long_arg_name + long_arg_name); 
 }`

to

`function foo(a,b){
alert(a+b); 
}`

Comment: You don't always get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin:

https://github.com/promatik/PHP-JS-CSS-Minifier

It uses this minifier http://javascript-minifier.com/

Or use this script from
http://javascript-minifier.com/examples

```
<?php
    // setup the URL, the JS and the form data
    $url = 'http://javascript-minifier.com/raw';
    $js = file_get_contents('./public/ready.js');
    $data = array(
        'input' => $js
    );

    // init the request, set some info, send it and finally close it
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $minified = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    // output the $minified
    echo $minified;
?>
```

Don't forget to cache everything :)

Comment: Hi there :) Are you already use the same minifier ? I try to use it by with this solution i get // input was empty